# how to integrate custom dropdown component and formik in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i'm new in formik and react typescript.
currently, i have a screen called `addScreen.tsx`. inside that screen, there is component called `<FormDropdown />`. component FormDropdown has a child component called `<Dropdown />`.

how i can get the value when dropdown item changed, then i passed on onsubmit formik in addScreen ?

thanks in advance

below are the snippet codes from every screen or component

```
// addscreen.tsx
<FormDropdown
  options={[
    {
      id: "what's your name?",
      label: "what's your name?",
    },
    {
      id: "where do you live?",
      label: "where do you live?",
    },
    {
      id: "what is your favorite food?",
      label: "what is your favorite food?",
    },
  ]}
  name="securityQuestion"
  data-testid="securityQuestion"
  className="block h-full w-full border-transparent px-3 py-2 text-base leading-[1.813rem] text-nero focus:border-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-0"
/>;
```

```
//its formik component named FormDropdown.tsx
import { useField } from "formik";
import React, { FC, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";

import { useUpdateEffect } from "@/hooks";

import Dropdown from "@/components/Dropdown";

import type { FormDropdownProps } from "../FormDropdown/types";

const FormDropdown: FC<FormDropdownProps> = (props) => {
  const { name } = props;

  const [, meta, helpers] = useField(name);

  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState<string | number>(
    meta.value || meta.initialValue
  );

  const hasError = useMemo(
    () => meta.touched && !!meta.error,
    [meta.error, meta.touched]
  );

  useUpdateEffect(() => {
    setCurrentValue(meta.value);
  }, [meta.value]);

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const text = event.target.value;

      setCurrentValue(text);
      helpers.setValue(text);
      helpers.setError("");
    },
    [helpers]
  );

  const handleBlur = useCallback(() => {
    helpers.setTouched(true);
  }, [helpers]);

  return (
    <Dropdown
      {...props}
      // value={currentValue}
      // hasError={hasError}
      // onChange={handleChange}
      // onBlur={handleBlur}
    />
  );
};

export default FormDropdown;
```

```
//Dropdown.tsx
import React, { FC, Fragment, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import clsxm from "@/utils/clsxm";

import Button from "@/components/Button";

import type { DropdownProps, Option } from "./types";
import Typography from "../Typography";

const Dropdown: FC<DropdownProps> = ({
  options,
  isScrolled = false,
  disabled = false,
  hasError = false,
  className,
}) => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<Option | null>(null);
  const [open, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const ref = useRef<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * Alert if clicked on outside of element
     */
    function handleClickOutside(event: any) {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setIsOpen(false);
      }
    }
    // Bind the event listener
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);

  const handleClick = (option: Option) => () => {
    setSelectedOption(option);
    handleOpenClick();
  };

  const handleOpenClick = () => {
    setIsOpen((open) => !open);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        className={clsxm(
          className,
          "w-full rounded-[0.938rem] border border-beluga bg-white p-[10rem] px-4 py-4 text-base font-medium text-improbable focus-within:border-improbable",
          hasError ? "border-poppySurprise" : ""
        )}
        aria-expanded="true"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={() => handleOpenClick()}
      >
        {selectedOption ? selectedOption.label : "Please Choose"}
      </button>
      {!disabled && open && (
        <div
          ref={ref}
          className={clsxm(
            "absolute z-20 mt-[0.625rem] w-[14.0625rem] overflow-hidden rounded-[0.938rem] border-[0.0625rem] border-beluga bg-white py-[1.25rem]",
            isScrolled && "h-[15.5rem] overflow-scroll overflow-x-hidden"
          )}
        >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <Fragment key={option.id}>
              <Button
                className={clsxm(
                  "h-[0.75rem] w-[8.125rem] rounded-none border-none bg-transparent hover:bg-white"
                )}
                onClick={handleClick(option)}
              >
                <Typography variant="p" size="text-sm" color="text-improbable">
                  {option.label}
                </Typography>
              </Button>
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: Formik already has internal state to keep track of the current value. Why are you adding your own state aswell with `currentValue`?

Comment: thanks for the comment @super, but currently still confusing to try an implement your suggestion.